# Laravel: PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php on line 500

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu

Since i upgraded my php version from 5.6 to 7.2, i have a persistant error on my php_errors.log:
`PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '?' in /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php on line 500`

On Line 500:

`return $factory->of($arguments[0], $arguments[1])->times($arguments[2] ?? null);`

I Search for this on stackoverflow, and the main cause is server still using php5.6, but i think it's not the reason. Platform is Laravel 5.7 and apparently is all working fine.

If i run `php -v` from the terminal i got PHP 7.2:

`PHP 7.2.12-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Nov 12 2018 09:55:12)(NTS)
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies with Zend OPcache v7.2.12-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies`

Some questions on stackoverflow suggest adding a phpinfo to show the php version used by the system, and actually is the correct:

[image: php info from my platform]

Even if i tried to disable old version, server says that php5.6 is already disabled:

`Module php5.6 already disabled`

With php5.6 disabled and php 7.2 up and running, what could be causing this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is on line #499, #500, and #501?

Comment: Line 500 seems to be  `return $factory->of($arguments[0], $arguments[1])->times($arguments[2] ?? null);`, which should work in 7.2. I'm not sure where you're running phpinfo from, but try creating the file within the public directory and browse to it, just in case it's running from a different ini.

Comment: Yeah, I'd put the `phpinfo()` call in Laravel's `public/index.php` to make sure *Laravel* is getting PHP 7.2. The error message you're getting is exactly what older PHP versions would say when encountering modern Laravel.

Comment: Did you update Laravel at the same time? The null coalescing operator `??` is only supported in PHP >= 7 so if you've always been running that Laravel version then PHP 5.6 should have been throwing that error this whole time.

Comment: are you using mod_php? did you restart Apache after switching to 7.2?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus yes, i upgraded Laravel at same time. Currently running Laravel 5.7.

Comment: 1. You should restart your nginx/apache as Joni said. 2. You should find line about php socket in nginx/apache config and rewrite it for new php  version.

Comment: @ceejayoz did it, and phpinfo shows php 7.2 :|

Comment: Try restarting your web server. Something is not adding up...

Comment: @Joni on phpinfo i have on loaded modules:  mod_php7 (and many others) and yes, i restart apache2.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus it works. I was trying to avoid a reboot since is the production server (I did the same on a DEV server and everything was fine without reboot).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved with a server reboot, as suggested by @MonkeyZeus. Apparently something was not adding up after upgrade both PHP and Laravel.

Answer (score 7):

This problem occurs because your version path is still 5.6 set it 7.2

SWITCHING between PHP versions

> sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php5.6
>
> sudo update-alternatives --set phar /usr/bin/phar5.6
>
> sudo update-alternatives --set phar.phar /usr/bin/phar.phar5.6
>
> sudo a2dismod php7.2
>
> sudo a2enmod php5.6

Switch into php 7.2

> sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.2
>
> sudo update-alternatives --set phar /usr/bin/phar7.2
>
> sudo update-alternatives --set phar.phar /usr/bin/phar.phar7.2
>
> sudo a2dismod php5.6
>
> sudo a2enmod php7.2